# Incorporate Gallery Slideshow into application?

Tags: android, slideshow

Is it possible to feed a list of images somehow to be displayed via the Gallery Slideshow feature? At present I have created something workable, but not as neat as Gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) for slideshow

[image]

Comment: Thank you, sir; seems to be just what I need.